# AFNetworking mixes Arrays?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I currently try to make 3 request to a web server. The returned data is a `json` dictionary with posts (news, events and obituaries). So I have to call 3 different urls to get my data. 
Thats the code I use to do this:

```
 - (void)search{
NSMutableArray *tempOperations = [NSMutableArray array];
// For every request, create operation
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {

    NSString* path;
    //Create NSURLRequest
    if (x == 0){
        path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"get_search_results/?s=%@&post_type=post&count=5&orderby=date&secure=bla",_searchPhrase];
    } else if (x==1){
        path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"get_search_results/?s=%@&post_type=veranstaltung&count=5&orderby=date&secure=bla",_searchPhrase];
    } else if (x==2){
        path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"get_search_results/?s=%@&post_type=todesanzeige&count=5&orderby=date&secure=bla",_searchPhrase];
    }

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:nil];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData];

    // AFNetworking Request
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    // Add request to array
    [tempOperations addObject:operation];

}

[client enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:tempOperations
                              progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfCompletedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {

                                  DLog(@"%d / %d", numberOfCompletedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);

                              } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
                                  int counter = 0;
                                  for (AFJSONRequestOperation *ro in operations) {

                                      if (ro.error) {

                                          DLog(@"++++++++++++++ Operation error");

                                      }else {

                                          id JSON = ro.responseJSON;

                                          if (counter == 0){
                                              newsArray = [(NSDictionary *)JSON objectForKey:@"posts"];
                                              DLog(@"Es wurden %i News mit %@ gefunden",[newsArray count],_searchPhrase);
                                              DLog(@"Path: %@",ro.request.URL);
                                          } else if (counter == 1){
                                              eventArray = [(NSDictionary *)JSON objectForKey:@"posts"];
                                              DLog(@"Es wurden %i Events mit %@ gefunden",[eventArray count],_searchPhrase);
                                              DLog(@"Path: %@",ro.request.URL);
                                          } else if (counter == 2){
                                              deathArray = [(NSDictionary *)JSON objectForKey:@"posts"];
                                              DLog(@"Es wurden %i Todesanzeigen mit %@ gefunden",[deathArray count],_searchPhrase);
                                              DLog(@"Path: %@",ro.request.URL);
                                          }
                                          counter++;

                                      }
                                  }

                                  [searchTable reloadData];

                              }];


  }
```

As you can see I have 3 different `NSMutableArrays` for the posts (`newsArray, eventArray, deathArray`) - but the problem is that after the request every `NSMutableArray` contains the data of my first request. Which means that now every Array contains news and not events or the deaths.

I don't know if this has something to do with caching and I already googled for hours but I'm still absolutely clueless. Maybe you can help me out.

best regards :)

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through your completion block?  When you log the URLs (`DLog(@"Path: %@",ro.request.URL);`) do they output as you expect?

Comment: Yes the URL's are always right, but the JSON I do get back is always the one from the first request.

Comment: What happens if you type your URLs directly in a browser, do you get three different results?

Comment: Yep, if I open them in the browser I receive three different jsons

Comment: We now also changed the headers on the server to prevent caching - but the problem still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting them using method calls.

i.e

```
self.newsarray = ...
```

You're trying to set a variable from within a block

Usually you do it using a `__block` decalartion on the variable. But assuming the three arrays are properties the using the `self.` syntax means the variables will be set by a method call which also works.

Comment: The problem is that I get for 3 requests the same JSON (and I don't) know why. So I guess the Arrays in general do work and I don't think that this would help me (or did I  missunderstood?)

Answer (score 0):

Operations do not finish in a defined order. Calculate the index by looking for the operation object in the original array:

```
for (AFJSONRequestOperation *ro in operations) {
    int counter = [tempOperations indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:ro];
    ...
}
```

Comment: This would explain incorrect ordering, but the OP is getting 3 identical copies of the first request.

Answer (score 0):

We now fixed the problem with updating to another AFNetworking version - now everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: you need to mark the question as answered with your own answer